# Programatically Modifying SharePoint List Item-level permissions using CSOM

Tags: development, document-library, permissions, client-object-model

I have a SharePoint 2013 (on-premises) document library named “**Reports**”. It inherits the parent site’s permissions (by default). It has a column named “**AssignedTo**” of type **People or Groups** (mandatory & multiple selections enabled). So whenever anyone is uploading a new document in that library, he has to input minimum one username in that field.
I need a **Client-object model (C#) code** that would do the following for each List Item in the “**Reports**” document library –

1. Remove all permissions from the list item which were granted access by default (inheritance) while adding the item to the library.
2. Only the **Owner** (i.e. the alias under **Created By** column) should have “Full **Control**” level of access to the list item.
3. Only the users added to the corresponding “**AssignedTo**” column for that list item should have “**Edit**” access to that list item.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why use CSOM and not a SharePoint 2010 workflow with an Impersonation Step?

Comment: :) That is because they (the client) wants it like that. Also I have very minimal knowledge in workflows. If possible, can you share any document(s)/blog that can help me? It'll be good for learning. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace CustomReportsPermission
 {
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        string siteUrl = "THE_FULL_SITE_URL";
        string docLibName = "Test";
        string accessToUsers = "Assigned"; 
        string author = "Author";

        p.ModifyPermissions(siteUrl, docLibName, accessToUsers, author);

        //Exit with Sucess code
        Console.WriteLine("Permissions modified successfully!");
        Environment.Exit(2000);
    }

    private void ModifyPermissions(String site, string docLib, string accessToUsers, string author)
    {
        try
        {
                ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(site);
                SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(docLib);

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(collListItem);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
                    {               
                            clientContext.Load(oListItem,item => item[accessToUsers]);               
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();               

                            oListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false,false);              
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                            string authorName = ((FieldUserValue)oListItem.FieldValues["Author"]).LookupValue.ToString();
                            User authorUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(authorName);
                            clientContext.Load(authorUser);

                            if (oListItem["Assigned"] != null)

                            foreach (FieldUserValue userValue in oListItem["Assigned"]as FieldUserValue[])
                               {
                                string assignedName = userValue.LookupValue.ToString();
                                User assignedUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(assignedName);
                                clientContext.Load(assignedUser);
                                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                                RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBindingAssignee = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
                                collRoleDefinitionBindingAssignee.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor)); //Set permission type
                                oListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(assignedUser, collRoleDefinitionBindingAssignee); 
                               }

                            RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBindingAuthor = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
                            collRoleDefinitionBindingAuthor.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Administrator)); //Set permission type
                            oListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(authorUser, collRoleDefinitionBindingAuthor); 
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is the full working code. Made a small change to the code suggested by Ruslan. :)

Answer (score 3):

It have to be something like this:

```
    string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Reports");

    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(collListItem);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
    {               
        clientContext.Load(oListItem,item => item["AssignedTo"]);               
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();               

        oListItem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);              
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        FieldUserValue authorsValue = (FieldUserValue)oListItem["Author"];                              
        User authorUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(authorValue.LookupValue);
        clientContext.Load(authorUser);

        FieldUserValue[] assignedValues = ((FieldUserValue[])oListItem["AssignedTo"])[0];               
        foreach (FieldUserValue assignedValue in assignedValues)
        {
            User assignedUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(assignedValue.LookupValue);
            clientContext.Load(assignedUser);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBindingAssignee = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
            collRoleDefinitionBindingAssignee.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor)); //Set permission type
            oListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(authorUser, collRoleDefinitionBindingAssignee);               
        }

        RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBindingAuthor = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
        collRoleDefinitionBindingAuthor.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Administrator)); //Set permission type
        oListItem.RoleAssignments.Add(authorUser, collRoleDefinitionBindingAuthor);             

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();           
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ruslan, I was trying to work with your code and got the following error: "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue'" at the line "FieldUserValue assignedValue = (FieldUserValue)oListItem["AssignedTo"];". This is maybe because AssignedTo column is "multiple selections" enabled and more than one username can be provided. So I think you have to use an array. Can you please modify the code accordingly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

a PowerShell script using the Client Side Object Model – the script is executed every night.

- The script iterates through a couple of lists each night a performs a
  couple of actions: Checks for new items
- Based on the list item data, find the column ‘EmployeeId’ and query
  active directory to find the User Principle Name (UPN) (EmployeID is
  stored against each user in AD).
- If the above action finds a user from AD the script removes all
  permissions on the list item and sets unique permissions so only the
  employee and a management group have access to that list item.

The following code snippets assume a connection to SharePoint is open (ClientContext), and the current web is loaded into context.

To find the SharePoint group the following was used:

```
   # Load in list of groups on the current web.
$groups = $web.SiteGroups
$ctx.Load($groups)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Find the group called HR. Note - using GetGroupByName was not working, therefore I had to iterate through the groups.

foreach($group in $groups)
{

if($group.Title -eq "hr")
{
$hrGrp = $group.Id
}
}

# Get the group and load into context to be used.
$spGrp = $groups.GetById($hrGrp)
$ctx.Load($spGrp);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

To set item level permission on each list item:

```
# Get the list by Title and load.
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyListcctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$listTitle = $list.Title

# Simple query - purely used to ensure all data is returned.
$camlQuery = New-Object microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$camlQuery.ViewXml = "10000"

# Load in the items.
$collListItem = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)
$ctx.Load($collListItem)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Iterate through each item.
foreach ($item in $collListItem)
{   
    # reset variable to ensure no false positives.
    $upn = $null
    $user = $null
    $roleAssignment = $null 
    $continue = $false

    # Set a couple of variable, get the user from AD based on employee number.
    $recordId = $item.Id
    $upn = Get-Upn -eid $item["EmployeeID"]
    $continue = $false

    if($upn -ne $null)
    {
        $continue = $true
    }
    else
    {
        Add-LogMessage "ERROR: Missing employee number on record '$recordId' "
    }   

    if($continue)
    {
        # Break inheritance on the list item and remove existing permissons.
        $item.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $true)

        # Get the permissions role for 'Read' and 'Edit'.
        $reader = $web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Read");
        $Editor = $web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Edit");

        # Create a role assignment and apply the 'read' role.
        $roleAssignment = New-Object microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
        $roleAssignment.Add($reader)

        # Create a role assignment for editors - applying the 'edit' role.
        $roleAssignmentEditor = New-Object microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($ctx)
        $roleAssignmentEditor.Add($Editor)

        # Ensure the user exists on the site level, using EnsureUser.
        $user = $ctx.Site.RootWeb.EnsureUser($upn)
        $ctx.Load($user)

        # Apply the two permission roles to the list item.
        # $user is a SharePoint user.
        $ctx.Load($item.RoleAssignments.Add($user, $roleAssignment))    
        # spGrp is the HR group returned in the above snippet.
        $ctx.Load($item.RoleAssignments.Add($spGrp, $roleAssignmentEditor))

        # Update field on the list item to show it has ben processed.
        $item["A001"] = "PROCESSED"
        $item.Update()
    }

    # Execute changes.
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

http://dhendry.wordpress.com/2014/08/14/sharepoint-item-level-permissions-using-powershell-and-csom/

**But if you want a workflow to set the item level permission check the below**

http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3911751/Implementing-ItemLevel-Security-in-SharePoint-2010-and-2007.htm

http://johnliu.net/blog/2010/7/13/sharepoint-2010-configuring-list-item-permissions-with-workf.html